# Implement mathematical equation for Loss function in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, mathematical-expressions

I implemented a GAN model and I would like the discriminator (UNET Discriminator) to compute decision over all pixels and [D(x)]i,j refer to the discriminator decision at pixel (i; j). The original loss in the paper is based on a vanilla Loss, but I would like to use a WGAN-GP loss in my case.                                                           How can I implement the below equation in pytorch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw83k.png)

Comment: it's a bit unclear, implement for/as what. what is your goal?

Comment: It is `D(x).sum()` for an appropriate definition of `D`.

Comment: @GuyNachshon, I implemented a GAN model and I would like the discriminator (UNET Discriminator) to compute decision over all pixels and  [D(x)]i,j refer to the discriminator
decision at pixel (i; j). The original loss in the paper is based on a vanilla Loss, but I would like to use a WGAN-GP loss in myy case.

Comment: @erip what about the (i,j)?

Comment: If `D(x)` is a matrix, `D(x).sum()` is the same as `D(x).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=0)` which covers `i` (rows) and `j` (columns).

Comment: @erip D(x) is a tensor of scores, where D is the discriminator model and x is the input image!

Comment: A model is a function from `R^m` to `R^n` so `D(x)` is in `R^n`. You need to sum over all dims which aren't the batch dim which is what your image is showing. For more help you'll need to add code.

Comment: @erip I added more details above!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.